# How to Access the controls in the caption of the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I want to put a title to my gridview ,so i do the following :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_employee" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption='<table width="100%" class="TestCssStyle"><tr><td class="text_Title"><asp:Label runat="server" Id="lbl_gv_title"></asp:Label></td><td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="ibtn_edit_master"  ImageUrl="~/Images/editsmall.png" ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:ImageButton></td></tr></table>'
        CssClass="forms" DataKeyNames="valueskey" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_inbox_PageIndexChanging"
        OnRowCommand="gv_inbox_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gv_inbox_RowDataBound" TabIndex="2"
        Width="600px">

    </asp:GridView>
```

---

I want to access the label and the image button in the caption of my gridview to set the value of the label and to  handle the event of the button so i can change the label value .How to do this ?

Comment: can you see the controls in the caption? I don't think server controls will work in caption, at least I can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving asp controls lablel and image button ,you can give html controls
 element as caption.Then you can assign divid.innerHtml=gridviewid.caption.Tostring(),and you can write client side script for that input element button.